# setClickable() is not working on button

Tags: android, layout, button, view

I want to make button unclickable using setClicable() but it's not working. I am using inflater because I need.
This is my code:

```
mContactList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contactList);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
for (ListIterator<ContactModel> it = contactList.listIterator(); it.hasNext();){
        ContactModel contact = it.next();

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_unknown_list_row, null);
view.findViewById(R.id.inviteButton).setTag(contact.getEmail());
view.findViewById(R.id.inviteButton).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {                   
        String address = (String) v.getTag();
        sendInvatoin(address);
        if(v.findViewById(R.id.inviteButton).isClickable())
        v.findViewById(R.id.inviteButton).setClickable(false);
    }
    });
mContactList.addView(view);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using.

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

In your case, you will do something like this:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.inviteButton).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {                   
        String address = (String) v.getTag();
        sendInvitatoins(address);
        Button b = (Button)v;
        b.setEnabled(false);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When using setOnClickListener, unclickable views (= v.setClickable(false)) would become clickable as mentioned in Docs.

> ... a callback to be invoked when this view is clicked. If this
>   view is not clickable, it becomes clickable.

Better to use v.setEnabled(false) if you want to set an OnClickListener to the button or any other view...

Answer (score 1):

This will work in case of Imageview as well as the button.

```
private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        if (imageview.isEnabled()){
            //I have wrapped all code inside onClick() in this if condition
            //Your onClick() code will only execute if the imageview is enabled
            //Now we can use setEnabled() instead of setClickable() everywhere
        }}
    };
```

Inside `onCreate()`, you can do `setEnabled(false)` which will be equivalent to setClickable(false).

We are able to use `setEnabled()` as tag because it's state remains unaffected on invocation of click (unlike `setClickable()` whose state changes).